# Unable to type text in text pin field(sms_autofill: ^2.2.0)

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdown, autofill

unable to type OTP CODE in text pin field (sms_autofill: ^2.2.0) when the timer is on, I can write after the timer is off, debug log show "view is not EditText"

I declared int to set time

```
Timer? _timer;
int _start = 60;
```

Method to call timer, this timer is called when otp send successfully.

```
  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) {
        if (_start == 0) {
          setState(() {
            timer.cancel();
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _start--;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Otp Field to enter otp

```
PinFieldAutoFill(
   codeLength: 6,
   decoration: const UnderlineDecoration(
   bgColorBuilder: FixedColorBuilder(Colors.white),
   textStyle: TextStyle(
   fontSize: 22,
   color: Colors.black,
   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
   colorBuilder: FixedColorBuilder(Colors.white),),
                currentCode: _code,
                onCodeSubmitted: (code) {
                  setState(() {
                    _code = code;
                  });
                  if (code.length == 6) {
                    setState(() {
                      isLoading2 = true;
                    });
                    handleSignIn();
                  } else {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: 'Enter Correct Code',
                        backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.95),
                        textColor: Colors.white);
                  }
                },
                onCodeChanged: (code) {
                  if (code!.length == 6) {
                    FocusScope.of(this.context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    setState(() {
                      _code = code;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
```

[image: This video describes my issue]

Comment: But above code is working fine my side.

Comment: Do you use a timer on the screen?

Comment: I have just pasted your code.

Comment: The code works when the timer is off, the problem occurs when the timer starts

Comment: Please add that code as well so that I can reproduce your error.

Comment: please see the updated question.

Comment: Okay and where are you calling startTimer function?

Comment: Are you updating _timer afetr every second?

Comment: After sending OTP from Firebase startTimer() function call and for showing time i used _start int as a text widget

Comment: Problem is in your function check my answer.

Comment: So how can i fix this? can you please provide any fix for this issue.

Comment: For that just remove the setState

Comment: is there any specific reason to call the setState or calling Timer.periodic ?

Comment: Removing from setState timer started, but "text(_start )" don't change the Upcoming seconds.

Comment: Are you using any State Management tolol like Provider, Bloc, GetX?

Comment: I do not use any of the plugins you specify, I just simply create "_startTimer()" to start time and for show time just use "_start ".

Comment: Basically timer will call for sometime until the _start turns 0 right?

Comment: The timer is simply shown so that the user can resend the OTP after the timer expires.

Comment: Try using this package for your timer https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_countdown_timer

Comment: issue has been solved?

Comment: Problem solved after using **flutter_countdown_timer** package,

Comment: Okay then please mark this question as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is in your void **startTimer()** function when you call it first time it `initiates` a **Timer.periodic** function where you are calling `setState` in every second. So any change in your screen will not reflect because set state is setting it again to default `value` every `second`.